# Simulator will quote "No to the file or directory"

Tags: ios, swift

Enter the code shown below

```
 if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("resource", ofType: "zip"){
       let fileManager:NSFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
       try! fileManager.copyItemAtPath(path, toPath: documnets)

 }
```

There is no problem on the real machine,The Simulator will quote "No to the file or directory"。

Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a)

Comment: Does *documnets* really exist in the file system of the simulator?

Comment: What is your intention ?